# Stack Overflow's invasion

Tags: visual, steganography

I came back to Puzzling earlier today and had a strange feeling that Stack Overflow has invaded. Can you find out evidences of Stack Overflow's invasion from the following image?

> [image]

**Note:** The answer is in the image above. Guessing "ciphered" meanings of the text description is a wrong way.

#### Hint 1

> If you try to solve this puzzle just by examining what you see in the image (visual content, like text or figures), you're not doing it the right way.

#### Hint 2

> The image is processed and is not a raw (original) screenshot. The expected solution is manually injected during the processing.

Comment: Hm, I think that rot13(vzthe qryrgrf vzntr zrgnqngn).

Comment: @EKons No that's not the case. I've verified that the expected solution is still valid.

Comment: Woohoo, I make an appearance in all the chat rooms

Comment: @EKons Wanna check the accepted answer for the solution? `:)`

Comment: I read that as "Stack Overflow has been invaded"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use...

> https://osric.com/chris/steganography/decode.html to decode the image you get:
>
>  [image: result]
>
>  This clearly shows that the "Puzzling" logo on the top left has been changed to "Stack Overflow".
>
> [Edit from OP:] Alternatively, you can use other software to extract the LSB of the red channel of the image, and you'll get the same result as shown above.

Comment: WOW! Never thought of that... Nice one! +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton and that's what Hint 2 means

Comment: Oh I see now, +1 to the question as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just found out these were wrong :
1.

> The Log in and sign up buttons should be on the left, instead of right, to the logos of feed, achievements, etc.

2.

> The word "Questions" should be boxed

Whereas this should be correct:

> The “Hot network questions” are missing

Comment: did you read hint 2?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry @iBug

Answer (score 0):

I can clearly see the invasion.

Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Laugh out loud LOL

Comment: LOL very creative! Still not the expected answer yet.